# Get all subsets of fairly large set of elements, {1,2,3,...,254,255}, that sum up to a value 666

Tags: sum, subset, np-complete

While there are many answers to this sort of question, many of them do not handle large sets or sums well.  I want to get all subsets of set {1,2,3,...,254,255} that sum up to a value 666, and actually get some results in a reasonable amount of time (say 10 minutes).

Heuristics are welcome, because I think this is an NP-complete problem.  Dynamic programming may be a good approach.  A program to produce at least 10 results would be great--Any program that I've tried has taken too long.  Pointers to other stackoverflow answers welcome.

If you like, produce the results by hand.  An algorithm would be better.

Comment: This question should be asked on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well, you need at least 36 items and at most 666, so you have those limits.  Right?  The set `{1,2,3,...,35,36}` adds up to 666.  There are at least 36 sets with 35 entries (drop 1 and 36, add 37; drop 2 and 35, asd 37; drop 3 and 34, add 37, etc.)

Comment: @TimRoberts sets don't have duplicate elements.   One has to start from the same starting set each time.  Yes, the algorithm will work with that caveat, and produce 18 sets.  One can increment 37 to 38, 39 ... and get many more sets.  So that's for subsets with  36 elements, one can go to 37 elements, 38 elements, etc.